# Linq - How to refactor a multiline output using the same list

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to know what's a better way to improve this Linq set of code. 
Using xamarin forms and data binding. I need to pass individual fields to different labels and they all come from the same main list. I need to select those individuals items to pass them to each of the respective binding fields since each is expecting an only string.

```
var nameloc = MainList.Select(d => string.IsNullOrEmpty(d.name) ? "Not Available":d.name).FirstOrDefault();
var descrip = MainList.Select(d => string.IsNullOrEmpty(d.descr) ? "Not Available":d.descr).FirstOrDefault();
var cap = MainList.Select(d => string.IsNullOrEmpty(d.cap) ? "Not Available":d.cap).FirstOrDefault();
var ruls= MainList.Select(d => string.IsNullOrEmpty(d.ruls) ? "Not Available":d.ruls).FirstOrDefault();
var name = MainList.Select(d => string.IsNullOrEmpty(d.nameAddress) ? "Not Available":d.nameAddress).FirstOrDefault();
var email = MainList.Select(d => string.IsNullOrEmpty(d.EmailAddress) ? "Not Available":d.EmailAddress).FirstOrDefault();
var phone = MainList.Select(d => string.IsNullOrEmpty(d.phone) ? "Not Available":d.phone).FirstOrDefault();
LC = nameloc;
Description = descrip;
Cat = cap;
Rules = ruls;
Name = name;
Phone = phone;
email = email;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your code has the perhaps slightly odd behaviour that if `MainList` is empty, each of the final strings are all `null`.

If this is intentional, you can add a helper function like this:

```
string ValueOrNotAvalable(MainListItem item, string value)
{
    if (item == null)
        return null;
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? "Not Available" : value;
}

var firstItem = MainList.FirstOrDefault();

LC = ValueOrNotAvalable(firstItem, firstItem?.name);
Description = ValueOrNotAvailable(firstItem, firstItem?.descr);
...
```

If you actually wanted to use the string "Not Available" if `MainList` is empty, you can simplify it a bit:

```
string ValueOrNotAvailable(string value) => string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? "Not Available" : value;

var firstItem = MainList.FirstOrDefault();

LC = ValueOrNotAvalable(firstItem?.name);
Description = ValueOrNotAvailable(firstItem?.descr);
...
```

Comment: actually I want to replace any null or empty value with "Not available". so you think the last approach you mentioned will work?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you this approach:

```
var item = MainList.Select(x => 
    new { 
        name = string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.name) ? "Not Available" : x.name,
        //Same for other properties
    }
).FirstOrDefault();
LC = item.name;
//Same for other properties
```

Answer (score 1):

It makes no sense to use Linq in this way. The only collection-oriented operation in your code is the call to `.FirstOrDefault()`. Simply do that, and then add a helper method for getting the fallback string if the input is null or empty, e.g.:

```
public static string GetPropertyWithFallback(Item item, Func<Item, string> getter) {
  if (item != null) {
    var val = getter(item);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(val)) {
      return val;
    }
  }
  return "Not available";
}


public static void Main() {
  var mainList = new List<Item>();

  var firstItem = mainList.FirstOrDefault();
  var name = GetPropertyWithFallback(firstItem, i => i.Name);
  var descr = GetPropertyWithFallback(firstItem, i => i.Descr); 
  //etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the minimalist approach would be using a lambda expression as parameter to get your values. So something like this might work -

```
//assumed class for demonstration only
public class Data
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string desc { get; set; }
}

//extension method 
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static string GetFirstProperty(this List<Data> list, Expression<Func<Data, string>> predicate)
    {
        //you can ignore the compilation here, if you use Func<Data,string> instead of Expression<Func<Data,string>>
        var compiledSelector = predicate.Compile();
        return list.Select(x => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(compiledSelector(x)) ? "Not Available" : compiledSelector(x)).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}

var name = MainList.GetFirstProperty(x => x.name);
var desc = MainList.GetFirstProperty(x => x.desc);
```

I assumed the data class. Use your own class as needed.